# LINQ query to get XML elements when an attribute is not present

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have this XML:

```
<Config>
  <EmpFieldsMap>
    <Employee>
      <Field>
        <Name update = "false">EmpNumber</Name>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name insert = "true">EmpName</Name>
      </Field>
      <Field>
        <Name insert = "true">EmpDesignation</Name>
      </Field>
    </Employee>
  </EmpFieldsMap>
</Config>
```

My application will do an an INSERT or UPDATE for which the fields will come from this xml.
Each tag will have either the insert or the update attribute as shown in the snippet above.

For Insert all the tags that have the attribute

```
insert = "true"
```

and the tags that don't have this attribute, in this case the 'EmpNumber', have to be considered.

The same applies for update.

This code gives me all the tags with the insert attribute set to true:

```
insertTags = from p in xml.Element("Config").Element("EmpFieldsMap").Elements("Field")
             where p.Element("Name").Attribute("insert") != null 
             && p.Element("Name").Attribute("insert").Value == "true"
             select p.Element("Name").Value;
```

Removing the check for null

```
insertTags = from p in xml.Element("Config").Element("EmpFieldsMap").Elements("Field")
             where p.Element("Name").Attribute("insert").Value == "true"
             select p.Element("Name").Value;
```

gives

> *Object Reference not set to an instance*

error.

I am having trouble composing a query that will also include the tags where the attribute is not present.

Can someone please help me with this?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insertTags = from p in xml.Element("Config").Element("EmpFieldsMap").Elements("Field")
    where (p.Element("Name").Attribute("insert") ?? "true") == "true"
    select p.Element("Name").Value;
```

Comment: @Gero - That's the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).  If the `insert` attribute returns null, it is instead replaced with `true`.

Answer (score 0):

With XPath and Linq it even simpler:

```
XPathSelectElements(@"Config/EmpFieldsMap/Employee/Field/Name[@insert='true']")
```

Also for this particular xml you can use global search for name elements:

```
var insertTags = xdoc.XPathSelectElements(@"//Name[@insert='true']")
                     .Select(n => (string)n);
```

Or with Linq query syntax:

```
var insertTags = from n in xdoc.Descendants("Name")
                 where (string)n.Attribute("insert") == "true"
                 select (string)n;
```

When you cast node value to string, it will not throw exception if node is missing. Simply `null` will be returned. So, you don't need all that stuff (which is btw even **not compilable**):

```
(p.Element("Name").Attribute("insert") ?? "true") == "true"
```

---

**One more edit**. If you are dealing with booleans, then use booleans instead of strings:

```
var insertTags = from n in xdoc.Descendants("Name")
                 where (bool?)n.Attribute("insert") == true
                 select (string)n;
```

How it works? Nullable boolean will have `null` value for missing attributes. Comparing `bool?` which do not have value with any boolean value produces `false`. So, you will get only those elements, which have required attribute, and which have `true` for that attribute.